# Georeference a binary grid file?

Tags: qgis, python, coordinate-system, gdal, wgs84

I currently have X amount of binary files that are in grid format.

I have the span of these files in the form of latitude/longitude, plus the geographic projection. How can I turn these into georeferenced geoTIFFs/HDF/netCDFs?

For reference the latitude span is -60 to 60, and the longitude span is 85 to 205.

Data is projected in EPSG:4326.

Comment: Can you use python? By binary grid do you mean .adf format or .bil/bsq/raw? How do you have the span information? Is it a table or part of the file name etc.

Comment: I can use Python (and have been). For reference, it can be processed using numpy.fromfile().reshape().

Comment: As for format, I'm not sure. It's more like `.bin`. The span is given as outside information.

Comment: You can embed a known georeference if you have the origin (upper left) and extent,  divide the dX by cols to get X cell size and dY by rows to get Y cell size then use SetGeotransform() (y is usually negative)  like on this page https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html (ctrl + f for setgeo). What is the raster? According to GDAL docs it could be ENVI - ENVI .hdr Labelled Raster, (is there a .hdr file?) but was the data geographical or projected when the georeference was lost?

Comment: Data is projected. It is in the projection EPSG:4326.

Comment: EPSG:4326 is a geographical spatial reference (units: degree) so is *unprojected*. Projected data would have units: feet or metre. If the data was projected when it lost its georeference you would need to apply a projected GeoTransform or the data will not be accurate even though you have your extent and origin in degrees, you would need to generate the corners, project and build a GeoTransform from those coords.

Comment: Whoops, you're right. I apologize, I'm new to this. I think I have figured it out actually. Thanks.

Comment: That's ok, we were all beginners once. How did you end up fixing these files? If you have an answer please share it with us by answering your own question.

Comment: @MichaelStimson I have posted my solution below.

Comment: Building a `VRT` file around the binary data should also be possible. If you can upload a sample file, I can investigate further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I ended up solving it:

```
cols = array.shape[1]
rows = array.shape[0]
originX = 85 # starting longitude, top left
originY = -60 # starting latitude, top left
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff') # load the GTiff driver
outRaster = driver.Create(fileName, cols, rows, 1, gdal.GDT_Int16) # create the raster layer
outRaster.SetGeoTransform((originX, pixelWidth, 0, originY, 0, pixelHeight))
outband = outRaster.GetRasterBand(1)
outband.SetNoDataValue(-1)
outband.WriteArray(array) # write the binary file to the TIFF
outRasterSRS = osr.SpatialReference()
outRasterSRS.ImportFromEPSG(4326) # import the EPSG projection
outRaster.SetProjection(outRasterSRS.ExportToWkt()) # sets the projection for the tiff
outband.FlushCache() # flush the cache
```

Comment: +1 Can you include the calcs for pixelWidth and pixelHeight please.

Comment: Values for pixelWidth and pixelHeight were given as 0.01.